# How can I style a select element on an Android phone?

Tags: html, css

I am developing a mobile website and testing on both iPhone and android phone.
I changed the appearance of select boxes on the page using CSS.

This displays good in the iPhone browser, but in Android does not apply the styles correctly.
The original dropdown arrow remains present (and is stretched vertically due to the height property).

Is there any way of telling the browser how to style this element on a android device? Or is it not supported?

Here is a sample of my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="filter-group">
    <select class="bigInput" id="f_eventWho" name="f_eventWho" tabindex="1">
        <option id="f_public" selected="selected">For Everyone</option>
        <option id="f_private">By invitation</option>
        <option id="f_both">All Gatherings</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bigInput
{width: 125px;
height: 50px;
background-size: 15px;
background: rgb(159, 209, 225) url(../img/small_down_arrow_20.png) no-repeat right;
border: none;
margin: 5px;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: They will be styled according the Browser/OS/Device, the same way you cannot change the appearance of a radio button.

Answer (score 5):

There is no consistent way to style native selectboxes in browsers, let alone in mobile.

The best workaround I've found is to create an HTML dropdown that emulates the selectbox behavior - I highly recommend SelectBoxIt if you're using JQuery: http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

All you have to do is call `$('select').selectboxit();` and it replaces all select boxes on the page with stylable html elements that behave the exact same way. Best of luck!

Comment: Would I be right in saying that this would show the select items on screen when clicked, as opposed to the browser-native lists that pop up like an app menu on many phone browsers ?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to not try and style select elements, especially not on mobile devices.

Doing so is both damaging to usability and performance, it's raising your middle finger to visitors and letting them know you really don't care about them at all.

Please try and justify the enormous overhead (please look at what a lib like selectBoxIt will do to page-weight) you will be adding against the benefit you will provide to visitors (which is zero, at best).

Comment: The benefit of a plugin like SelectBoxIt is more than just styling. You also get a ton of helpful events to listen to and API methods that you can use (which normal select boxes do not have). These events/methods may be critical to your application. Also, you will not damage usability since SelectBoxIt uses the native mobile wheel interface by default for mobile browsers.  On top of that, I have provided a custom build tool for developers to use: http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/customDownload.html

Comment: Thanks Gregg, but those are potential benefits to developers, not visitors. Usability can also be impacted by page-weight and load times, so even with the default 'do nothing for mobile selects' approach you can still affect UX by adding to the page load. As I said, responsible developers should always try and justify the benefits against these trade-offs before implementing such solutions.

Comment: @Greg Franko I had a look at 'selectBoxIt' and I am using iPhone 8+ with iOS12.2. 'selectBoxIt' only seems to change the styling on the select display element, but not the select options. The select options still display in a spin wheel at the bottom of the page. I thought that 'selectBoxIt' would allow us to create a desktop-like select list with options that drop down from the select element.